# Magento block rewrite not working

Tags: magento, url-rewriting, block

I am simply trying to rewrite a community extension block, with another, created in the same location.

I want to extend block:
**Belvg_Stores_Block_Front**

using:
**Belvg_Stores_Block_StoreLocator**

Class header code:

```
class Belvg_Stores_Block_StoreLocator extends Belvg_Stores_Block_Front
```

Config.xml code(i added the rewrite section):

```
<blocks>
    <stores>
    <class>Belvg_Stores_Block</class>
</stores>
<rewrite>
    <stores_front>
    Belvg_Stores_Block_StoreLocator
    </stores_front>
    </rewrite>
</blocks>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're close. try this;

```
<blocks>
    <stores>
        <class>Belvg_Stores_Block</class>
        <rewrite>
            <front>Belvg_Stores_Block_StoreLocator</front>
        </rewrite>
    </stores>
</blocks>
```

Comment: hi..that gave me a whitescreen...but seems that was to do with another problem. Just needed to clarify the correct xml i guess!
Many thanks.